# PowerBi DAX create a datatable with a range of 5 days. (previous 2 days,current day, next 2 days) excluding weekends

Tags: powerbi, dax

The problem i have is that i can not get my code to work consistantly
Sometimes the dates are displayed correctly but for example today my code shows next friday instead of last friday.

```
5 dagen = 
VAR CurrentDate = TODAY()
VAR CustomCalendar =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            CALENDAR ( CurrentDate - 4, CurrentDate + 4 ),
            WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ) >= 1 && WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ) <= 5
            && [Date] <> CurrentDate - 3
            && [Date] <> CurrentDate + 3
        ),
        "DayOfWeek", WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ),
        "FormattedDateDutch",
        VAR EngDay = FORMAT ( [Date], "ddd" )
        VAR DayOfMonth = DAY ( [Date] )
        VAR MonthOfYear = MONTH ( [Date] )
        RETURN
            SWITCH (
                TRUE (),
                EngDay = "Mon", "Ma",
                EngDay = "Tue", "Di",
                EngDay = "Wed", "Wo",
                EngDay = "Thu", "Do",
                EngDay = "Fri", "Vr",
                EngDay = "Sat", "Za",
                "Zo"
            ) & " " & FORMAT ( DayOfMonth, "00" ) & "-" & FORMAT ( MonthOfYear, "00" )
    )
RETURN
    CustomCalendar
```

This is what should happen:
if Today = Monday:

- Last Thursday
- Last Friday
- Monday(Today)
- Next Tuesday
- Next Wednesday

if Today = Tuesday

- Last Friday
- Last Monday
- Tuesday(Today)
- Next Wednesday
- Next Thursday

if Today = Wednesday

- Last Monday
- Last Tuesday
- Wednesday (Today)
- Next Thursday
- Next Friday

if Today = Thursday

- Last Tuesday
- Last wednesday
- Thursday (Today)
- Next Friday
- Next Monday

if Today = Friday

- Last Wednesday
- Last Thursday
- Friday(Today)
- Next Monday
- Next Tuesday

---

Today it shows
Date
12-10-2023 00:00:00
16-10-2023 00:00:00
17-10-2023 00:00:00
18-10-2023 00:00:00
20-10-2023 00:00:00

At the moment i am lost on what to do.
My DAX knowledge is still work in progress and i dont know how i can get it to work consistantly

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are causing you the issue:

```
   && [Date] <> CurrentDate - 3
   && [Date] <> CurrentDate + 3
```

Replace them with

```
   && ABS(NETWORKDAYS([Date], CurrentDate)) < 4
```

And you should be golden.
Another tip is you can use locale in `FORMAT` so you could just have
`FORMAT( [Date], "ddd dd-mm", "nl")` for your Dutch date.

Altogether:

```js
5 dagen = 
VAR CurrentDate = TODAY() // DATE(2023, 10, 16)
VAR CustomCalendar =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            CALENDAR ( CurrentDate - 4, CurrentDate + 4 ),
            WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ) >= 1 && WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ) <= 5
            && ABS(NETWORKDAYS([Date], CurrentDate)) < 4
        ),
        "DayOfWeek", WEEKDAY ( [Date], 2 ),
        "FormattedDateDutch", FORMAT( [Date], "ddd dd-mm", "nl")
    )
RETURN
    CustomCalendar
```